# iOS Scrolling Interface - FoodSpotting signup interface

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm not sure if you guys have checked out the sign-in/sign-up interface for the iPhone app "FoodSpotting
, but it's pretty cool. Somehow they're able to move what seems to be a UITableView vertically downwards to create an entirely new view with a slick animation. It essentially looks like they're moving the entire screen down, but yet when you try and scroll back up to the original sign-in screen you can't.

Does anybody know how to get this kind of functionality with either a UITableView, ScrollView, or regular UIView? If you need more clarification on the kind of animation I'm talking about either download the app or I can try and post pictures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I actually built that page! It's pretty simple: It's just two UITableViews, and a simple Core Animation animation is used to "scroll" between the two. I suppose a similar effect can be achieved using only one tableview, although using two separate ones allows us to take advantage of the individual tableview's scrolling behavior to do things like move the form up when the keyboard appears.

**EDIT:**

I know this is SUUUPER late, but here's a quick explanation...

My controller is a UIViewController subclass, not a UITableViewController. In the viewcontroller's view, I set up two tableviews like this...

[image]

- Black = Status Bar
- Red = Screen Area
- Blue = Top TableView
- Green = Bottom TableView, positioned just offscreen

The code to transition between the two is pretty simple...

```
//transition to bottom tableview
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_TIME animations:^{
    bottomTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.view.frame.size.height);
    topTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.view.frame.size.height); 
}];

…

//and to return to original state…
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_TIME animations:^{
    bottomTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    topTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; 
}];
```

Comment: wow that's awesome. So could you provide some sample code for the Core Animation? I have the 2 tableviewcontrollers, but I still don't quite understand how to scroll between the two. Do you have one "sign-up/login" view that has 2 UITableViewControllers in it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks though this really clears things up and helps me understand how you implemented this. Very nice!

Comment: hey, most people would have just left it. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. It's a UIScrollView on UIView. By default scrollview is scrollable and on completing sign up View is animated.

So this will be easy to implement.

Comment: So do they nest a UITableView inside a UIScrollView? Because the 2 entry forms (textfields) seem to be in a UITableView Section......also, would you mind further explaining how you would create this kind of an animation? It's pretty cool and I was wondering if somebody could provide a small bit of sample code...Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably avoid nesting scrollable elements (such as UITableViews and UIScrollViews). See my answer for an explanation of how we built that page in Foodspotting.